# Cómo me conecto a SQL Server 2017?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

Descargué SQL Server Managment Studio 2017 y ni bien abro el programa me solicita que ingrese un nombre de servidor. Ingreso el nombre de mi pc (DESKTOP-8I8P0VU) y me muestra el siguiente error:

---

Cannot connect to DESKTOP-8I8P0VU.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=2&LinkId=20476

---

El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado

Alguno sabría qué debo hacer para solucionar este problema?

Gracias

Comment: ya probaste "localhost" ?

Comment: Ya he probado y nada, sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Lo unico que se me ocurre rapidamente es que hayas instalado el SQL Managemente pero no el motor de base de datos que es lo que te esta pidiendo.

Answer (score 0):

He resuelto mi problema. Todo lo que tenía que hacer era reinstalar SQL Server Expression, cuando lo instalé por primera vez, elegí "Instalación Personalizada" y debería seleccionar "Instalación Básica". Así que, primero tuve que desinstalar el Managment Studio y luego reinstalar el SQL Server. Y problema resuelto.

Answer (score 0):

Hola si tenes instalado el sql server version express tenes que poner lo siguiente:
.\SQLEXPRESS o si no el nombre de la version que tengas de sql en lugar de EXPRESS, espero que te sirva saludos

Comment: Realizaste una respuesta a una pregunta que el mismo se respondio.